# how to make a data fetch form in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want the user to have a form for fetching data from the database, for example, as in /admin:

[Form in admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYTI1.png)

So that the user can select multiple entries and, for example, delete them, how can I do this?

Comment: Please share your code...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify the django admin and add the functionality you need to use this package `from django.contrib import admin` to register your personal models by extending `admin.ModelAdmin`
To change the admin interface you need to override template files in .../site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/ Here is the full tutorial for more clarification
https://realpython.com/customize-django-admin-python/